# What is this 8 pin PCB to wire connector

Tags: pcb, connector

I have tried searching all over the internet, and haven't managed to get anywhere with this - does anyone know what this 8 pin PCB to wire connector is? It is approximately 18mm wide. It is used for both data and power (5v).

[image: 8 pin PCB wire connector]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One of the JST family... look them up for details

Comment: Looks like a "0.1 inch pitch right-angle shrouded keyed 1 row 8 way header".  Or at least that's what I'd look for on my favourite vendor's search filters.

Comment: Measure the pitch of the pins.  That is: the distance from the center of one pin to another.  This could be either a 2mm or 0.1" pitch - hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers! I've measured the pitch, and it's 2mm. I believe it is a JST 2.0mm PH 8-pin connector. I'll submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connector has a 2mm pitch. I believe it is a JST 2.0mm PH 8-pin connector.

[image]

Comment: Well, technically the question is about a PCB mounted connector and this is not one.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know the actual pin spacing this is just a scientific guess but it APPEARS that you might be able to use these ( https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10853 ) connectors with that.